# Error while calling a function-Transferring variables between view controllers

Tags: swift, xcode

I wrote a function and called it ,however I am getting the following error:
editor placeholder in source file.I. want to transfer variables between view controllers.

here is the function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vd = segue.destination as? profile2
    vd!.name = self.name
    vd!.mail = self.mail
}
```

and here is the call:

```
self.prepare(for: <#UIStoryboardSegue#>, sender: <#Any?#>)
```

this is where I get the error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `#` and all those `< >`s?

Comment: You should not be calling prepare for segue yourself.  The framework should call that for you when you are about to transition between controllers.  It seems you may understand something here.

Comment: I can't find a way to transfer the name and the mail to another view controller

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you call a segue.

You call a segue by `self.performSegue(withIdentifier "segueIdentifier",sender: nil)` and this will in fact call prepare(for segue:sender:) for you. Or if you are not using manual segues, but you connected them in storyboard, you don't need to call the function at all, the system will do that for you automatically.

And you also have editor placeholders in your call (the <> and # symbols).